# Xcode: iPod Touch Simulator?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipod-touch, simulator

I'd like to test my app on the ipod touch. But in Xcode I don't see a simulator for this (I only see a simulator for iphone 3gs, iphone 4, and ipad).

Do you know if there's a way to run an ipod touch simulator?

Comment: Why won't the iPhone simulator work for you, considering the almost-identical nature of the two products?

Comment: The simulator isn't even close enough to the iPhone (in memory or performance or connectivity) for it to matter.

Comment: It's not the same, the iPod Touch has half as much memory, and doesn't allow the same size textures as an iPhone or iPad. I see bugs on the iPod Touch that I do not see on an iPhone of the same generation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the iPhone simulator. For simulation purposes, it is the same.

Comment: it's not the same. i'm having a bug on itouch that i'm not having on iphone sim/iphone.

Comment: i'm having a crash in ipod devices and can't replicate it in any other device, probably in simulator are the same but in real device have something of difference running apps.

Comment: Note I said in my answer "for simulation purposes". If you're trying to debug something that's only happening on a device, use the device. The simulator and the device are not the same. But if you're testing out basic features, UI, layout, and the like, it's sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it matter? The Simulator isn't simulating the actual hardware differences here. For example, it doesn't provide a camera. The only difference between "iPhone" and "iPhone 4" is the screen resolution, and in fact the most recent version of the simulator doesn't even say "iPhone 4", it now says "iPhone (Retina)". Similarly the only real difference between "iPhone" and "iPad" is the screen size and the chrome the simulator presents.

Comment: By "most recent" do you mean the one that comes with iOS SDK 4.2?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, which is too bad.  My app plays sound through the speaker or through the receiver based on user's choice.  But if on an iPod or iPad, there is no receiver, and the choice button should not be presented to the user.  I can detect the difference between an iPhone and other device types, but I can't simulate what happens on an iP[oa]d.